# how to limit bandwidth on azure website through portal?

Tags: azure

I have multiple website on azure, and I wonder if there is any way to limit the bandwidth usage, for example pause the website if the bandwidth exceeds a certain value?

Is that something i can do through azure portal?

I have a pay as you go account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Azure Web Sites does not offer a way to limit the bandwidth explicitly. You can "implicitly" limit the bandwidth by using smaller instances, which have less throughput.

Why are you trying to limit the outgoing bandwidth? Is it for containing costs?

(Disclaimer: I work for the Azure field team at Microsoft Canada)

Comment: because some times I host website for clients and don't want them to exceed the bandwidth which will cost me more, and I have same case with some personal websites

Comment: If that's your goal, I don't think App Service would work for you. I'd suggest using virtual machines with panels like cPanel, which can limit bandwidth for each website, for example.